# CaseTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.FinalException: SObject row does not allow errors

Tags: trigger

I have a field "DA Name" in Case object in which I am populating the value from "CaseTeamMember" object only when "Status" changes. This I am doing through Trigger. I do not want anyone to update this field manually or from back-end. For this I am trying to add a error message via TRIGGER on the "DA Name" field when anyone is trying to update it. But I am receiving the trigger error instead of my Custom Error.

[image]

Below is the Trigger:

```
Trigger CaseTrigger on Case (After Insert , After Update , Before Update) 
{
     If(Trigger.Is After)
     {
         IF(Trigger.isUpdate)
         {
            IF((C.Record_Type_Name__c == 'Delivery Escalation')  && (Trigger.oldMap.get(C.Id).Status != Trigger.newMap.get(C.Id).Status))
            {
                CaseTriggerHelper.CaseAuditMethod(Trigger.Old,Trigger.New);
            }

            IF((Trigger.oldMap.get(C.Id).Status == Trigger.newMap.get(C.Id).Status) && (Trigger.oldMap.get(C.Id).DA_Name__c != Trigger.newMap.get(C.Id).DA_Name__c))  
            {
                CaseTriggerHelper.ErrorOnModifyingDAName(Trigger.New);
            } 
         }
     }
}
```

Below is the Trigger Class

```
Public Class CaseTriggerHelper
{
     //This method is written to create new "Case Status History" record whenever the Case status is updated. And to update DA Name field from CaseTeamMember object
    Public Static Void CaseAuditMethod(List<Case> CaseOldIds , List<Case> CaseNewIds)
    {       
        
    //**Code to Update DA Name on Case Detail Page**
    Set<Id> CaseId = New Set<Id>();
    
    For(Case C : CaseNewIds)
    {
        CaseId.add(C.ID);
    }
    
    List<Case> CaseList = [Select Id,Status,DA_Name__c from Case where Id =: CaseId];
    List<CaseTeamMember> CaseTM = [Select Id,MemberId,Member.Name,ParentId,TeamRoleId,TeamRole.Name from CaseTeamMember where ParentId =: CaseId];
    
    Try{
    For(Case C : CaseList)
    {
        For(CaseTeamMember CTM : CaseTM)
        {
            If(C.Id == CTM.ParentId)
            {
                If(C.Status == 'DA Working' && CTM.TeamRole.Name == 'DA')
                {
                    C.DA_Name__c = CTM.Member.Name;
                    System.debug('---C.DA_Name__c---'+C.DA_Name__c);
                } 
            }
        }
        Update C;
    }
   }
    Catch(Exception e){
        } 
   //**Update ends here**     
}

    //To avoid updating the field DA Name
    Public Static Void ErrorOnModifyingDAName(List<Case> CaseIds)
    {
        Set<Id> CaseId = New Set<Id>();
        String DAName = 'Null';
        
        For(Case C : CaseIds)
        {
            CaseId.add(C.ID);
        }
        
        List<Case> CaseList = [Select Id,Status,DA_Name__c from Case where Id =: CaseId];
        List<CaseTeamMember> CaseTM = [Select Id,MemberId,Member.Name,ParentId,TeamRoleId,TeamRole.Name from CaseTeamMember where ParentId =: CaseId];
        
        Try{
        For(Case C : CaseList)
        {
            For(CaseTeamMember CTM : CaseTM)
            {
                If(C.Id == CTM.ParentId)
                {
                    If(C.Status == 'DA Working' && CTM.TeamRole.Name == 'DA')
                    {
                        DAName = CTM.Member.Name;
                    } 
                    
                    If(C.DA_Name__c != DAName)
                    {
                        C.DA_Name__c.adderror('DA Name field should not be modified.');    
                       ***//I am getting the Error in above line. This is line 208.***
                    }
                }
            }
        }}
        Catch(Exception e){
            }
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue ?

Thanks!

Comment: `C.DA_Name__c.adderror('DA Name field should not be modified.');` instead `C.adderror('DA Name field should not be modified.');` try like this

Comment: also why are you quering it again?

Comment: @Ratan : I had tried initially C.adderror('DA Name field should not be modified.');. But I had received the same error.

Comment: @Ruchi instead of `caselist` use `CaseNewIds`

Comment: @TusharSharma : Thanks Tushar...This resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ruchi instead of caselist use CaseNewIds. Also don't query all records again.

because `adderror` works with trigger syntax. If you query the records then you will lost the syntax thats why you are facing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you querying the case object again, and also DML should be out of for loop in the first method.

```
    Public Class CaseTriggerHelper
    {
         //This method is written to create new "Case Status History" record whenever the Case status is updated. And to update DA Name field from CaseTeamMember object
        Public Static Void CaseAuditMethod(List<Case> CaseOldIds , List<Case> CaseNewIds)
        {       

        //**Code to Update DA Name on Case Detail Page**
        Set<Id> CaseId = New Set<Id>();

        For(Case C : CaseNewIds)
        {
            CaseId.add(C.ID);
        }

        List<Case> CaseList = [Select Id,Status,DA_Name__c from Case where Id =: CaseId];
        List<CaseTeamMember> CaseTM = [Select Id,MemberId,Member.Name,ParentId,TeamRoleId,TeamRole.Name from CaseTeamMember where ParentId =: CaseId];
    list<Case> updatedCases = new list<Case>();
        Try{
        For(Case C : CaseList )
        {
            For(CaseTeamMember CTM : CaseTM)
            {
                If(C.Id == CTM.ParentId)
                {
                    If(C.Status == 'DA Working' && CTM.TeamRole.Name == 'DA')
                    {
                        C.DA_Name__c = CTM.Member.Name;
                        System.debug('---C.DA_Name__c---'+C.DA_Name__c);
                        updatedCases.add(C);
                     } 
                }
            }

        }
update updatedCases ;
       }
        Catch(Exception e){
            } 
       //**Update ends here**     
    }

        //To avoid updating the field DA Name
        Public Static Void ErrorOnModifyingDAName(List<Case> CaseIds)
        {
            Set<Id> CaseId = New Set<Id>();
            String DAName = 'Null';

            For(Case C : CaseIds)
            {
                CaseId.add(C.ID);
            }

           // List<Case> CaseList = [Select Id,Status,DA_Name__c from Case where Id =: CaseId];
            List<CaseTeamMember> CaseTM = [Select Id,MemberId,Member.Name,ParentId,TeamRoleId,TeamRole.Name from CaseTeamMember where ParentId =: CaseId];

            Try{
            For(Case C : CaseIds)
            {
                For(CaseTeamMember CTM : CaseTM)
                {
                    If(C.Id == CTM.ParentId)
                    {
                        If(C.Status == 'DA Working' && CTM.TeamRole.Name == 'DA')
                        {
                            DAName = CTM.Member.Name;
                        } 

                        If(C.DA_Name__c != DAName)
                        {
                            C.adderror('DA Name field should not be modified.');    
                           ***//I am getting the Error in above line. This is line 208.***
                        }
                    }
                }
            }}
            Catch(Exception e){
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: C.adderror('DA Name field should not be modified.');  also gives me the same issue. I had tried this even before.